# what is the status of css nesting modules?

Tags: css, w3c

In LESS/SASS you can nest css modules like this:

```
.sidebar {
   .title {..}
}
```

https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/

this says it was in draft for CSS3. So where is it?

Comment: I don't think it's implemented in CSS itself, but does it matter? since all CSS preprocessors (SASS, LESS, Stylus ❤ ) do support nesting.

Comment: If you're asking about the module's development status, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2701

Answer (score 1):

It's still in draft. There's apparently going to be an ampersand before nested selectors.

```
.sidebar {
  & .title {
    color: green;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is no longer needed according to https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nesting/?ck_subscriber_id=1020409247